# Can I disable SSH Server on a desktop computer (Debian) without impact?

Tags: ssh, desktop, debian

I do have an SSH Server listening on my desktop computer (Debian). From the `auth.log` I got for example:

```
sshd[808]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
```

My question is: Is it safe to disable SSH completely (also on startup) without losing the login functionality into the desktop environment?

Comment: I don't think that this really belongs here. It's more a Question like: If I disable one Component of my Linux System, are there any backslashes to that.

Answer (score 3):

When you start a session in a Linux environment, you have two choices:

- X environment, using a display manager.
- CLI environment, using a TTY.

According to your question, you're interested in the first one, so you can safely disable SSH if you will not need it.

The simplest solution is just to run `systemctl disable sshd.service`. As SSH is a basic service in a Linux system, uninstalling it may lead to some important dependencies being removed, so my suggestion is to just disable it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to login to your desktop or any pc remotely then it's ok to disable SSH. If you don't need then delete/disable the ssh package by the following commands,

To remove just ssh package itself

```
$sudo apt-get remove ssh
```

To delete configuration and/or data files of ssh and it's dependencies

```
$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ssh
```

To disable ssh service

```
$sudo systemctl disable ssh
```

for older debian version

```
$sudo update-rc.d ssh remove
```

Comment: No, don't uninstall SSH. It handles a whole lot of other things like outgoing connections, git, just to name a few. Instead disable the SSH server with service or systemctl.

Comment: As far i know remove doesn't remove the packages concurrently, purge does.

Comment: remove removes the packages, purge removes the packages as well as configuration files